# Determine how much ethylacetate is formed from reaction equation

Tags: equilibrium, mole

I have the reaction:

$$\ce{C2H5OH(l) + CH3COOH(l) <=> CH3COOC2H5(l) + H2O(l)}$$

and want to calculate how much ethylacetate is formed if I have $\pu{3 mol}$ of ethanol and $\pu{1 mol}$ of acetic acid. $K = 4.12$

This is how I calculated this:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\ce{C2H5OH} & \ce{CH3COOH} & \ce{<=>} & \ce{CH3COOC2H5} & \ce{H2O}\\\hline
 \pu{3 mol} & \pu{1 mol}  &   & - & -\\\hline
 3-x & 1-x  & & x &x\\
\end{array}
$$

$$\begin{align}K &= \frac{x^2}{(3-x)(1-x)} = 4.12\\[1.5em]
4.12 &= \frac{x^2}{x^2 - 4x+3}\\[1.5em]
x^2 - 5.28x + 3.96 &=0\end{align}$$

solving for x:

$$x = \frac{5.28 \pm \sqrt{(-5.28)^2 - 4(3.96)}}{2}$$

**why do I have to choose the negative sign here?**

$$x = \frac{5.28 - \sqrt{(-5.28)^2 - 4(3.96)}}{2} = 0.905$$

**How do I know that I have to choose the negative sign?** Is it because if I take the positive sign then $x=\pu{4.375mol}$ which is more than the mole of ethanol? So I should always choose the $x$ that is less than greatest amount of reactant?

Comment: Not all the roots of polynomial equations have physical/chemical meaning. You cannot get more of acetate than there was the acetic acid, can you ? You have already restrictions in place 0<=x<=1

Comment: Please take a look at [this posting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86) to learn more about the preferred use of MathJax on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, there are two possible options: the one where you add the square root and the one where you subtract it.

However, chemically only one of the two makes sense. If you were to add the square root, you would receive:

$$x = \frac{5.28 + \sqrt{(5.28)^2 - 4 \times 3.96}}{2} = 4.37$$

As this dimensionless value is – according to your initial table – supposed to be a quantity in moles which you subtract from the $\pu{3 mol}$ of ethanol and $\pu{1mol}$ of acetic acid, this would give you $\pu{-1.37mol}$ of ethanol and $\pu{-3.37mol}$ of acetic acid at equilibrium. This is impossible according to the rules of science and the universe as we know it. So while this answer is mathematically sound it is chemically meaningless.